# kivy on_dropfile multiple bindings

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, kivy, kivy-language

Is it possible to bind `on_dropfile` in multiple objects? Or is it always just one bind?

I've decalred class

```
class dropFile(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(dropFile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=lambda w, p: setattr(helper, 'mpos', p))
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.on_dropfile)

    def on_dropfile(self, *args):
        print ("ding")
        if (self.center_x - self.width/2 < helper.mpos[0] < self.center_x + self.width/2 and
                self.center_x - self.height/2 < helper.mpos[1] < self.center_y + self.height/2):
            print('dong')
            self.text = str(args[1])
```

and in kv I just use it as

```
dropFile:
    text: "Please drop file1"
dropFile:
    text: "Please drop file2"
```

But in only works on the first field (it only sees files that are dropped on the "Please drop file1" field, in other case it receives a drop, but fails to acknowledge that it is in bounds of second field, as if it only binds the `on_dropfile` function of first object).

Is there any elegant way to implement it for multiple objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it makes more sense to me. In this case, why don't you just make a list and execute whatever function you like on `Window.on_dropfile`?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<DropFile>:
<Box>:
    DropFile:
        text: 'left'
    DropFile:
        text: 'right'
''')

class Box(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        self.drops = []
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.handledrops)
        return Box()
    def handledrops(self, *args):
        for i in self.drops:
            i(*args)

class Helper:
    pass

class DropFile(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DropFile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=lambda w, p: setattr(Helper, 'mpos', p))
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.drops.append(self.on_dropfile)

    def on_dropfile(self, *args):
        print ("ding")
        if (self.center_x - self.width/2 < Helper.mpos[0] < self.center_x + self.width/2 and
                self.center_x - self.height/2 < Helper.mpos[1] < self.center_y + self.height/2):
            print('dong')
            self.text = str(args[1])

Test().run()
```

Seems working to me pretty well. Exceptions with `Window` related directly to `on_dropfile` handle in the App class, the other in their corresponding functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I do know how classes work.
Helper is just an empty `class Helper` to hold mouse position, I've moved the line ` Window.bind(mouse_pos=lambda w, p: setattr(helper, 'mpos', p))` to the main class later on, so it don't get executed multiple times. 
And it don't work like `on_release`, because `on_dropfile` is a window event and not widget event unfortunately and I cannot bind it from kv as it throws exceptions.
I've moved to PyQt as it seems more suitable for desktop apps (Kivy might say it's for all, but is streamlined for mobile).
But the question is still valid

Comment: Thanks, for the new edit, that seems to work much better :-)